# Gradual Increase in Progressbar in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, progress-bar

I have created a progress bar in VC++.

But this progress bar is not showing gradual increase. It dances to and fro in the Level.

```
myCtrl.Create( WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect  (100,140,300,170), this, 1 );
myCtrl.SetRange(0,100);
myCtrl.SetStep(2);
myCtrl.SetPos(0);

for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
{
    myCtrl.StepIt();
}
```

Please tell me how to show the gradual increase in progress bar

Comment: So you set the range to 100 and you call `StepIt` 10000 times? Seems legit.

Comment: Actually i want to upload a file and depends on that the progress bar should run. Please guide me on this

Comment: Set the max range to the size of the file. While transfering, set the position to the number of bytes transferred.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a lead :

- Get a percentage [0..100]
- Step only if necessary

In a thread do something like :

```
if (round(100.0 * file.bytesLoaded / (double)file.totalBytes) > myCtrl.Getpos()) {
     myCtrl.StepIt();
     myCtrl.UpdateWindow();
}
Thread.Sleep(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it, it will turn around and around.

You use StepIt if you know the number of steps you will take, so it will reach the end taking them.

The other approach is to use OffsetPos. Say yo set the rang to the byt count of file and OffsetPos to the amount of bytes already processed. As those are expected to be large, an improves solution could calculate the percentage, and use that, keeping the 0-100 range.

Nice documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkb2hwtk.aspx) and on adjacent pages.